# swift gesture recognizer tableviewcell get overruled

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uigesturerecognizer, uitableviewrowaction, swift4

I am using [AKSideMenu](https://github.com/dogo/AKSideMenu) to have a menu which appears by swiping from right to left.
In this side menu, I have a table view which cells are also swipeable (delete).

Now I am not sure why the horizontal swipe on the cells is not get recognized.

Here is an example App to be able to reproduce this error:

***(Parallax example)***

https://github.com/exocode/AKSideMenu
[image]

Here is a Demo to explore the Issue:

(Parallax)
https://github.com/exocode/AKSideMenu

Answer (score 0):

It seems the pan gesture recognizer is overridden in the library which might be messing with TableView Cell gesture recognizers.